# Restart Windows Defender on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I would like to restart Windows Defender without rebooting my PC. Is this possible?

I do not want to disable it permanently.

I have tried the following methods:

- "End Process" on MsMpEng.exe from elevated task Manager --> **Access denied**
- "End Process" on MsMpEng.exe from elevated Resource--> **Access denied**
- In services.msc, the Start/Stop entries are greyed out, it does not even offer any UI element to stop.
- In elevated command prompt, `psexec -s taskkill /im MsMpEng.exe /f` gives **Access is denied**.
- Opening a system command prompt with `psexec -i -s CMD` and then `sc stop WinDefend` gives **Access is denied.**
- Killing the parent process (services.exe) causes a BSOD.
- Clicking "Go to service" from Task Manager, then in the Services tab of Task Manager, right-click "Restart" on WinDefend. (The service does not restart)
- Stopping "Security Center" service. (That stops, but MsMpEng remains running)

Some other websites suggested using Group Policy editor, however that is not available in the Home edition of Windows 10.

---

The reason for this is that MsMpEng is leaking memory, it just continuouslyincreases its commit. I have seen it over 20GB.  This has only happened since installing the recent Creators Update. I'd like to restart it and see if that frees things up.

[image: MsMpEng leak]